What's the easiest way to contract and expand folded patterns?
I'm trying to create a folding paper thing like shown in this video https://bramfritz.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/paravent_base_grid_1-1.mp4
It goes from being somewhat flat, to scrunched up into a design, just like how paper would work IRL if you scrunched it up.


I'm thinking about doing rigid body physics, but is that the best way to go about it?
